# matrix filling, but it is skipping an element each row, why?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I have these vectors as follows

```
vector< vector< Arc * > * > _adjacences;
vector <int> list[_adjacences.size()];
vector <int> listD[_adjacences.size()];
vector < vector <int> > matrix( _adjacences.size(), vector<int>(_adjacences.size(),0 ));
vector < vector <int> > shortPath( _adjacences.size(), vector<int>(_adjacences.size(),0 ));
```

I want to make the adjacency list to an adjacency matrix

Arc contains these:

```
int sommetArrive;
int longueur;
string nom;
```

I tried to make two vectors one for the distance and the other for the peeks

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++){
     for (auto j : *_adjacences[i]){
          list[i].push_back(j->sommetArrive);
          listD[i].push_back(j->longueur);
     }
}
```

Then I make the adjacency matrix, **THIS IS WHERE I'M DOING THINGS WRONG**

```
for (int i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++) {
     for (auto j : list[i]){
          for (auto k : listD[i]){
               matrix[i][j] = k;
          }
     }
}
```

Instead of getting this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 120 0 62 
0 0 253 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 204 0 0 0 0 0 
0 53 0 12 0 0 105 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 15 0 38 0 0 108 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 93 0 123 0 0 113 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 158 0 0 0 0 118 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 97 0 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 87 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 103 0 0 3 0 53 0 0 0 73 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 153 0 0 33 0 113 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 55 0 0 91 0 0 0 0 72 0 0
```

I end up with this

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 62 0 62 
0 0 204 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 204 0 0 0 0 0 
0 105 0 105 0 0 105 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 108 0 108 0 0 108 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 113 0 113 0 0 113 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 118 0 0 0 0 118 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 87 0 0 0 0 87 0 0 0 87 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 73 0 0 73 0 73 0 0 0 73 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 113 0 0 113 0 113 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 72 0 0 72 0 0 0 0 72 0 0
```

Where the same number is being repeated instead of passing to the next element k

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for every `i` you use the same list `listD[i]`. The inner loop:

```
for (auto k : listD[i]){
    matrix[i][j] = k;
}
```

will assign all values in `listD[i]`, one by one, to `matrix[i][j]`, until the final value remains. This is the same as writing `matrix[i][j] = listD[i].back()`.

You probably need to replace the inner loop with `matrix[i][j] = listD[i][j]`.

Comment: yeah that's what I did wrong, but I can't make listD[i][j] works because it's a 1D vector

Comment: It is a 2D data structure. It's just not very clear. Replace `vector <int> listD[_adjacences.size()]` with `std::vector<std::vector<int> > listD(_adjacences.size())`.